# Zero-length C-array binds to pointer type

Tags: c++, arrays

I recently wrote a function template which takes a reference to a C-array:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
void foo(T(&c_array)[N]);
```

Assuming T is a `char`, the length of the C-string is `N - 1` due to the null-terminator.  I realized I should probably handle the edge-case where `N == 0`, because then `N - 1` would be `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()`.

So in order to avoid the chaos that might ensue in the rare case that someone passes a zero-length array to this function, I placed a check for `N == 0`.

However, to my surprise, it seems that a zero-length array is actually not even an array type - or at least, that's what GCC seems to believe.  In fact, a zero-length array doesn't even *bind* to the above function signature, if a function with a pointer-type signature is available as a candidate.

Consider the following code:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
void foo(T(&array)[N])
{
    std::cout << "Array" << std::endl;
}

void foo(const void* p)
{
    std::cout << "Pointer" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char array1[10] = { };
    const char* pointer = 0;
    char array2[0] = { };

    foo(array1);
    foo(pointer);
    foo(array2);
}
```

With GCC 4.3.2, this outputs:

```
Array
Pointer
Pointer
```

Oddly, the zero-length array prefers to bind to the function that takes a *pointer type*.  So, is this a bug in GCC, or is there some obscure reason mandated by the C++ standard why this behavior is necessary?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the output of `printf("%p\n", array2);`?

Comment: In C, a zero-length array type is not permitted.  I'm not sure about C++.  I'm not sure if this is related to your problem.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: In C you can use a zero-sized array as the last element of a struct. You can't instantiate such a struct ,but you can cast a chunk of bytes to a pointer to such a struct and access that array within it with an index

Comment: Zero length arrays *do* exist in C++. Their type just can't be constructed by the usual `T[N]` construct. Notably that type *can* be constructed though by `new`, so `new int[0]` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - I would say zero length arrays *don't* exist in C++.  `new int[0]` doesn't return an array-type, but rather, a pointer type.

Comment: @Charles you are wrong. It doesn't matter what type `new int[0]` evaluates to. That expression creates an object whose type is an array of zero length, so they necessarily have to exist. It's [well known](http://herbsutter.com/2009/09/02/when-is-a-zero-length-array-okay/) that there [exist zero length arrays](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#982).

Comment: @Johannes Schaub, it looks like `new int[0]`, as well as `malloc(0)` return a non-null pointer to a region in the heap.  But what does it mean to say they create an "object whose type is an array of zero-length"?  The only type created that is meaningful to the C++ type-system is a *pointer* type.  In other words, the result of `new int[0]` won't bind to a function `template <class T, size_t N> void foo(T(&)[N]);`.  It will only bind to a function such as `void foo(int*);`  So what does it really mean to say that `new int[0]` creates an array-type of zero-length?

Comment: Rather, isn't it more accurate to say that `new int[0]` creates a pointer to a zero-length buffer on the heap?

Comment: @Charles you assume that types are just a compile time component. But they aren't. Types describe objects and expressions. An object is created on the heap, and that object certainly isn't a pointer. A container of zero integers is rather more like the inverse of a pointer. The expression that `new` evaluates to is described by a pointer type, but that's nothing to do with the type of the object created. To the C++ type system, that object type is important. Otherwise, `delete (new int[0]);` wouldn't be undefined behavior.

Comment: `new` is different to malloc, in that `malloc` doesn't create an object. It merely gives you raw storage, without any type associated to it yet. However it doesn't make too much sense for me to argue about C++. I just need to quote the Standard. See 5.3.4 "The new-expression attempts to create an object of the type-id (8.1) or new-type-id to which it is applied.
The type of that object is the allocated type.". This is actually different from C. C really hasn't zero length arrays (see how `malloc` and FAMs are specified in C - it tries hard not to say that a zero sized object is allocated).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As arrays must have greater than zero length, if your compiler erroneously accepts a definition of a zero-sized array then you're "safely" outside of the scope of the language standard. There's no need for you to handle the edge case of `N == 0`.

This is true in C++: 8.3.5 [dcl.array]: If the constant-expression (5.19) is present, it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.

Comment: I don't think "undefined behavior" is correct here. The program that tries to define a zero-length array should be ill-formed.

Comment: I see.  I'm surprised GCC doesn't emit a warning or error about this.

Comment: @Chares Salvia: It does for me; are you using `-std=c++98 -pedantic`?

Comment: no I was just compiling with warning flags.  But you're right - it emits an error if I use the `-pedantic` flag.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently ISO C forbids 0-length arrays, which is probably affecting how GCC tries to compile stuff. See this question for further details! [zero length arrays vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627364/zero-length-arrays-vs-pointers)

Comment: according to me ,this not completely true (see my comment on the question)

Answer (score 2):

The [GCC Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) has a whole thing on zero length arrays. This is a GCC extension as is somewhat analogous to incomplete arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for C (and probably also C++ in this case), defining a zero-length array is undefined behavior, so GCC probably does this because a) nothing's stopping it, and b) it prevents errors like the ones you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Zero-length arrays do not exist in C++. However if they did, here is how you could handle the case:

```
template <bool B, typename T>
struct disable_if;

template <typename T>
struct disable_if<false, T>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <class T, size_t N>
typename disable_if<N == 0, void>::type foo(T(&c_array)[N])
{
    std::cout << "inside template\n";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Zero sized array are only legal in C as the last element of atruct. Anything else is pointless.