# Strange behaviour of structures in C++ [part 1]

Tags: c++

Consider:

```
struct box
{
    int array[3];
};

int main()
{
    box a = {1};
}
```

If the above works in C++ then why doesn't the following work?

```
struct box
{
    int simple_int;
};

int main()
{
    box b = 2;
}
```

What is the reason?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Properly, the former would use `box a = { { 1 } }`, so that you have one set of braces for each aggregate. The outer set of braces is for the structure, and the inner set is for the array. However, the language allows you to omit inner braces.

In the latter, there are no inner braces to omit. You are not allowed to omit outer braces; you must have at least one set of braces to distinguish a list of initializers for an aggregate. In a sense, the braces say “Here is a list of things to put inside the aggregate.” When you write `box b = 2`, the compiler does not know you want to put `2` **inside** the aggregate. Instead, it looks like you are trying to initialize the `b` object (rather than part of it) to `2`. So the compiler tries to find a constructor or a conversion that changes a `2` into a `box`. When this fails, you get an error.

Comment: even we are allowed to declare int as: `int i = {10};`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I omitted that because it is not relevant and complicates the discussion. The question is why can we not omit braces, not why can we add them. And it is a special case for scalars that the language specification treats separately, not a part of the rules for aggregates.

Comment: @Eric Yes got! One should keep explanation simple on front of new guy.

Comment: @EricPostpischil:By `aggregates` do we mean the variables declared inside the structure?

Comment: @InsaneCoder: Roughly, an aggregate is an object made of other objects. For initialization purposes, an aggregate is an array or class with no user-declared constructors, no private or protected non-static data members, no base classes, and no virtual functions. A plain struct containing an array is an aggregate containing an aggregate.

Comment: @EricPostpischil :Does `box a={{10,20,30},50};` means that initialise `box a={10,20,30}`to some array and `50` to an integer.I am asking for this question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926524/strange-behaviour-of-structutes-in-cpart-2#17926660`.

Comment: @InsaneCoder no, that means initialize the array inside to `{10,20,30}`, and another element of the struct to `50`.

Comment: @AJMansfield: More precisely, it means initialize the **first member** of the struct, which **must be** an array or struct, to `{10, 20, 30}`, and initialize the next member to `50`. It will not go find the array to initialize if it is not the first member.

Answer (score 18):

It doesn't work because your syntax is wrong. You can add support for b = 2 with an implicit constructor, if that is what you want.

```
box b = {2}; // correct syntax with no constructor
```

Or

```
struct box
{
    // implicit constructor
    box(int i) : i(i) {}
    int i;
};

box b(2);
box c = 2;
```

Or

```
struct box
{
    explicit box(int i) : i(i) {}
    int i;
};

box b(2);
box c = 2; // disallowed
```

Comment: Neil that is quit similar as `char* s = "A"` and `char* s = {"A"}`  both are possible.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Actually `char *s = "A"` is not possible in C++11, anymore (without warning). You have to use `const`. (Well `char*` for string-literal is **deprecated**, to be pedantic)

Comment: @Nawaz interesting so I have to do either:  `const char* s = {"A"}` or  `const char* s = "A"` in C++11 **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Yes.

Comment: const char* s = {"A"} looks confusing, I would not use it.

Comment: @Nawaz Some days back I come to know about: [`int array[] = {};`](http://codepad.org/Q3RNPv32) compiles until you don't use `-pedantic-errors`

Comment: VS2012 error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Yes, it is because [zero-sized static arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c/9722672#9722672) are not allowed in C++.