# strange behaviour of structures in C++[part 2]

Tags: c++

This is in continuation with [Strange behaviour of structures in C++ part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925909/strange-behaviour-of-structures-in-c-part-1)

If I do this

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct box
{
    //int simple_int;
    int arr[3];
};
int main()
{
    box a={10,20,30};
    //box b={100};
    //cout<<b.simple_int<<"\n";
    cout<<a.arr[0];
}
```

**OUTPUT :** 10 which is correct.

But if i remove the comments.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct box
{
    int simple_int;
    int arr[3];
};
int main()
{
    box a={10,20,30};
    box b={100};
    cout<<b.simple_int<<"\n";
    cout<<a.arr[0];
}
```

**OUTPUT:** `100 20 //instead of 100 10`

Why?

Comment: It should be a={X, {10,20,30}} where X is whatever you want simple_int to be. I don't use this syntax often so I don't know why the first works, but with only an array it should be a={{10,20,30}}

Comment: It works because inner brackets are optional (see also Part 1 of this question, same answer)

Answer (score 10):

```
box a = {10, 20, 30};
```

will initialize a as:

```
a.simple_int = 10;
a.arr = {20, 30, 0};
```

When you output `a.arr[0]`, it will output 20, as expected.

Comment: Not `{20, 30, 30}`, but `{20, 30, 0}`

Comment: That is correct syntax? It shouldn't be as I say in the comments?

Answer (score 3):

Your code give the correct output.

Your struct will be initialized at :

```
a.simple_int = 10;
a.arr = {20, 30, 0};
```

So `a.arr[0]` will be 20.

Output of your program : `100 20` as expected.

If you want to avoid this kind of misunderstanding, initialize your structure more like :

```
box a = { 100, { 10, 20, 30 } };
```

With that, the result is :

```
a.simple_int == 100;
a.arr[0] == 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not initialize arrays like that. In the second example, your struct has an int and an array of ints. Your initialization of `a` doesn't correspond to anything and so the compiler partially fills it for you.

You could write `a = {5, {10, 20, 30}}` to make `a.simple_int` be `5` and make `a.arr` be an array of those 3 values.