# How to clean the lint warning in C?

Tags: c, loops, struct, lint

I have the following code in C:

Two sturct:

```
typedef struct
{
  int age;
  int phone; 
} Student;

typedef struct
{ 
  int classNum;
  Student student[1]; 
} ClassRoom;
```

And then I created memory for 10 students:

```
ClassRoom * classRoom =  (ClassRoom*)malloc(sizeof(ClassRoom) + sizeof(Student) * 9);
```

Then I try to loop through all the students:

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   classRoom->student[i].age = 20;
   classRoom->student[i].phone = 20;  
}
```

Then I got a lint warning:

```
Warning 662: Possible creation of out-of-bounds pointerby operator '[
```

Looks like it says this two lines has lint warnings:

```
classRoom->student[i].age = 20;
classRoom->student[i].phone = 20;
```

What is the problem and how to fix it? I can not change the struct of `ClassRoom`, and are there any way to solve it?

Comment: there are sizeof(ClassRoom) in the malloc

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf See 6.7.2.1

Comment: if you want a variable length array at the end of a struct, it needs to be declared with empty brackets, not a size

Comment: @SteveCox: there is already room for one student in str Classroom structure, therefore ho only allocates for 9 student more as he want apparently 10 students. All this look correct to me.

Comment: @SteveCox: with some compilers you cannot declare an array with empty brackets.

Comment: yes you can, that has been in the standard since k&r c

Comment: if you literally cannot change the struct, there's no way to resolve the lint issue. just ignore it

Comment: @SteveCox: not so sure about this, my old VC6 compiler show following warning when I use a zero sized array: `warning C4200: nonstandard extension used : zero-sized array in struct/union`.

Comment: that error should show up if you declare Student student[0];. Student student[] is standard compliant (see example 17 in the above linked standard)

Comment: @SteveCox: using [0] or [1] yields exactly the same warning with both VS6 and VS2012 compilers. BTW it's a warning, not an error.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I know it does, I just said it does. You're not supposed to use either of those.

Comment: @SteveCox: sorry, I meant "[0] or []" not "[0] or [1]" in my previous comment.

Comment: @MichaelWalz then VS isn't standard compliant and should be ignored in this case, since the question is tagged with C. (did you make sure it was the last element in the struct?)

Comment: @SteveCox: following links pretend the contrary : [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c), [Link2](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html). So in C90 it was not standard but in C99 it is standard.

Comment: @MichaelWalz What C99 6.7.2.1 §16 said is "**As a special case**, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may
have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member."

Comment: Any ways can work around it?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing unallocated memory in your `for` loop.

You can do this as

```
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   classRoom[i].student[1].age = 20;
   classRoom[i].student[1].phone = 20;  
}
```

Comment: thats not what he wants. he wants a variable number of students in the struct

Comment: it is the same, still I can not change any in the struct

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   classRoom->student[i].age = 20;
   classRoom->student[i].phone = 20;  
}
```

here you are using 10 objects but you allcated memory for only 9 objects. that is one thing to be noted.

```
ClassRoom * classRoom =  (ClassRoom*)malloc(sizeof(ClassRoom) + sizeof(Student) * 9);
```

this allcates memory for only 9 students so change it to

```
ClassRoom * classRoom =  (ClassRoom*)malloc(sizeof(ClassRoom) + sizeof(Student) * 10);
```

if you can change structure then can use,
for variable number of students craete

```
typedef struct
{ 
  int classNum;
  Student *student; 
} ClassRoom;
```

then allocate student[] a memory dynamically depending on number of students. treat student as a array with memory allocated dynamically

Comment: Hello, the ClassRoom struct can not be changed. I can not change it.

Comment: @ratzip ok. did you specify that in question? and you mean to use student[1] a array of size 1?

Comment: @ratzip ok. check that you allocated memory for only 9 students but accessing 10

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are trying to dereference unallocated memory using the `Student[i]` as the `structure Classroom` has only `1 Student` elements inside it. you should just allocate enough memory to hold `5 Classroom struct` and then loop through the `Classroom` structures using `Classroom[i]->Student`

Comment: There are memory for ten Student is allocated