# Structure definition in C

Tags: c, arrays, structure, definition

I want to define a structure on the following way:

```
typedef struct Info_s
{
 uint8   Size;
 uint8   Address;
 uint8   Pattern[Size];    
}Info_t;
```

As you can notice the size of the array Pattern is "Size" which is declared first in the same structure.

Is that correct?

Comment: No. It is not. Obviously `Size` doesn't have any value when defined.

Comment: A compiler can tell you if it's correct. Faster than it would have taken you to post this question.

Comment: So is there any solution?

Comment: You declare `Pattern` as a pointer.

Comment: Dynamic allocation is the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577094/array-of-size-0-at-the-end-of-struct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array declared as a struct field must either have an *integer constant expression* as its size or be a *flexible array member* with no size (`uint8 Pattern[];`). Your variant is neither.

If the array size in your case is a run-time value, you have two choices

1. Flexible array member `uint8 Pattern[];`, which will result in a "flat" struct. The proper amount of memory to accommodate the entire struct with the array of desired length will have to be allocated with `malloc` manually.
2. Pointer member `uint8 *Pattern;`, in which case your struct will become two-leveled. Memory for the struct itself and memory for the array will generally become two separate memory blocks allocated independently.

A flexible array member is typically a better idea (and matches your apparent original intent), unless you have some other requirements that would preclude that aproach.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. That is violating the rule. Compile the code and you will know it clearly.

Rather keep a `uint8*` and then allocate to it memory (using `malloc`,`realloc` etc) based on the value of `Size`.

And now if you increase or decraese the value `Size` as per that reallocate your memory.

Yes with this, you have to free the dynamically allocated memory when you are done working with it.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the array size `Size` in the declaration of `Pattern` and you will get a valid declaration of a structure with a flexible array member.:)

```
typedef struct Info_s
{
 uint8   Size;
 uint8   Address;
 uint8   Pattern[];    
}Info_t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Go with

```
uint8*   Pattern;
```

and use `malloc` to allocate its size once `Size` is known.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically allocate memory to the structure, you can do it in following way :

```
struct Info_s
{
 uint8   Address;
 uint8   Pattern[Size];    
};

int main()
{
       struct Info_s *no;
       int i, noOfRecords;
       printf("Enter no: ");
       scanf("%d", &noOfRecords);

       no=(struct Info_s*) malloc (noOfRecords * sizeof(struct course));

       for(i=0;i<noOfRecords;++i)
       {
          scanf(...);
       }
     .
     .
     .
     return 0;
}
```

You can also refer https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/structure-dynamic-memory-allocation for more information.