# when array initialized as [0] size.Still able to assign value

Tags: c++, arrays

Initially, array declared with zero. Still, the compiler is not throwing error.

```
int x_var[0];
cout<<"Hello World"<<x_var[0]<<endl; // <<<<<<<<<<<< prints random number

x_var[0]=1;                          // >>>>> compiler is not throwing error.
                                     // But initialized array as zero.It must throw error
cout<<"Hello World"<<x_var[0]<<endl; // <<<<<<<<<<<<Prints value 1
```

Comment: Index out of bounds is undefined behaviour in C++, not a compilation error or a runtime exception.

Comment: Arrays of size 0 are illegal in C++. The compiler should issue an error on the declaration `int x_var[0];`.

Comment: OT: "But initialized array as zero" well, no. You set the array size to zero

Comment: @dxiv The compiler should *print* an error. Exceptions are thrown. Compilation errors are printed.

Comment: @dxiv GCC [doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/bMCURQ) apparently, possibly because of the VLA extension.

Comment: For GCC use: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp` and you'll get a warning

Comment: @user207421 That was "throw" in English language, not C++ language ;-)

Comment: @dxiv It was a misleading use of a term of art in C++. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: @4386427 See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6180200) for example.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577430/4386427

Comment: Man, some compilers just have no Standards.

Comment: *the compiler should give a diagnostic if invoked in standard mode