# Is zero size array invalid in C struct?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I have compiled followin gprogram using GCC compiler on Ubuntu platform.

I am wondering why the following program is working fine in C?

Is it undefined behaviour?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct str 
{ 
    char arr[0];     
}; 

int main()
{
    struct str s;
    s.arr[0]=1; // I think it is invalid in C
    printf("%d\n", s.arr[0]);
      return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

and when I print `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(s));`. it is print `0`.

Comment: This is supported by gcc extension, IIRC.

Comment: It isn't valid C, but an obsolete gcc extension that shouldn't be used. [What happens if I define a 0-size array in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c/9723093#9723093)

Comment: Even if GCC compiles without warning (did you use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`?) the assignment `s.arr[0]=1;` is an out-of-bounds write access. This is undefined behaviour.