# Close file pointers in a array

Tags: c, for-loop, io, file-pointer

I'm wondering if there is a better way of closing file pointers that are in a array other than having a for loop go through the array:

```c
argc -= optind; argv += optind;

FILE *inputfiles[argc - 1];

int i;
for (i = 0; i < argc; i ++)
    inputfiles[i] = fopen(argv[i], "r");

fnctn(inputfiles);

int f;
for (f = 0; f < argc; f++)
    fclose(inputfiles[f]);
```

Comment: _Side note:_ For your code to work, you have to account for the fact that [upon entry to `main`], `argv[0]` is the program name. The easiest way is: `--argc; ++argv; FILE *inputfiles[argc];` Or, do: `FILE *inputfile[argc - 1]; --argc; ++argv;`

Comment: I know, I shift the options with `optind` but forgot to add it here

Answer (score 0):

[`fcloseall`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fcloseall.3.html) exists as a GNU extension. Do know that this also closes `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.

There is no analogue in [standard C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io).

You can also simply exit your program, and rely on the OS to clean shop. This is generally considered bad practice.

---

Even though I'm assuming it's mostly mock-code, it should be noted you have a handful of off-by-one errors in your example.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < argc - 1; i ++)
    inputfiles[i] = fopen(argv[i + 1], "r");

int f;
for (f = 0; f < argc - 1; f++)
    fclose(inputfiles[f]);
```

There's also the case wherein `argc` is `1`, and you will declare a zero-sized array (`FILE *inputfiles[1 - 1];`), which is [invalid in ISO C.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c)

Comment: That's good to know about, and I could use it in this program, but I want to use only standard C so, a `for` loop it is