# I tried to define a dynamically growing array using typedef and it works up to 79 index, beyond that it doesnt, can someone sort this out?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, typedef

Without giving an explicit size, it works up to index 79. It prints the value 200 at index 79, but when I increase the index by 1 that is 80, it prints nothing and program terminates.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int list[];
int main() {
   list myList{};
   myList[79]={200};
   cout<<myList[79]; // OUTPUT: 200
   return 0;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int list[];
int main() {
   list myList{};
   myList[80]={200};
   cout<<myList[80]; // No Output and Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's an example of undefined behavior.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "dynamically growing array" in C++. C++ does not work this way. The resulting code results in random memory corruption, which gets bad enough to cause an immediate crash only when you try to use that particular index, but the whole thing is undefined behavior.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. `list myList{};` is array of size 0.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I initialized the array with i using a loop, from 1 up to 79 and printed the whole array and it did print the values from 1 to 79 and beyond that it didn't. How could it be randomly initializing the indexes up to 79 and crash always at 80. Still confused. I mean how an array can be dynamically growing upto 79 without explicit size....

Comment: @churill it is getting complied as well as running bro.

Comment: I repeat: there is no such thing as a dynamically growing array in C++. Which part of this is unclear to you? And just because the program compiles doesn't mean that it will run correctly. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @HamzaKhan That means you are probably compiling with `g++`. Then you should add the flags `-Wall` and `-pedantic` to spot pontentially dangerous non-standard extensions. Zero-size arrays [are not allowed in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9723093/5105949).

Comment: Please consider spending some time in reading about the containers that the C++ Standard Library has to offer, like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: The array does not and can not grow.  By the language standard it is a fixed size at compile time. You are just accessing an array out of bounds. This is undefined behavior. One of the worst behaviors of UB is when broken code appears to work under some conditions even though it is broken.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The Unclear part is that how an array, without explicit size, is getting initialized upto 79th index when there is no dynamic array in c++?
Array is storing values from 1 to 79 and are also retrieved. 
And if it is getting initialized upto 79, what is hindering to from getting initialized beyond 79?

Comment: It's very simple: [undefined behavior means anything can happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132574/does-undefined-behavior-really-permit-anything-to-happen). In your specific case, with your specific compiler, C++ library, and operating system, there just happens to be, by random, some unused or not-yet used memory that's big enough to store 79 values. But that's only true, right this instant. Tomorrow, when you run the same program, this may no longer be the case. For others, the same program might work only up to 50 values. For others, it will crash immediately. Welcome to C++!

Comment: @HamzaKhan The behaviour you're seeing is pure chance/coincidence.  Please read about [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: hahaha Thankyou @SamVarshavchik Got your point.

Comment: I will definitely go through it...Thanks for writing @G.M.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, try to do the following:

```
list myList {};
cout << sizeof(myList) << endl;
// Prints 0, since no elements 
// Note, the number does not signifies the number of elements,
// it signifies the number of bytes.
```

The `int foo[]` is not a dynamically growing array, it is legacy of C and is as primitive as it can be. When you subscript an array, it **does not add an element at the index** (nor up to the index).

When you do the `myList[79]={200};` it does not creates an element, and especially does not populates the array up to this index. Here, your program just tries to access an **out of bound** memory location (*and does write to it, which may be the worst part of it all*). It does not matter whether it is `79` or `80`, either will lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Note, the `T foo[]` arrays have no convince for their user or any internal intelligence in them, they represent raw memory. There's no bounds checking, no implicit or explicit growing of the allocated memory.

It is **up to the programmer** that uses this type to ensure that subscript value is in the allowed range (up to the predetermined size of the array).

That's why C++ programmers **should use any appropriate Standard Library container** for any real world applications.

Comment: @rarwrex if myList[79]={200} is not creating an element then how come cout<<myList[79] prints 200 ? if it is accessing out of bounds memory location then shouldn't it print some garbage value instead of the value that I stored?

Comment: @HamzaKhan because it is undefined behavior first of all, in particular, because you **do command to assign a value** to this memory location. Read on a buffer overflow bug. Who knows what you've overwritten in memory with this assignment.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, the code is not legal C++. If your compiler accepts it, then your compiler settings are not strict enough.

If your compiler accepts it, then it treats it as a zero-size array, not as a *"dynamically growing array"*, which isn't a thing.

You're accessing the array out of bounds, so the behavior is underfined (as much as it applies to invalid C++).

Comment: if *cout<<myList[79]*  is accessing out of bounds memory location then shouldn't it print some garbage value instead of the value that I stored?

Comment: @HamzaKhan Undefined behavior can have any effect, including what you see. If you tried to read a value before writing, it could've been garbage.