# Why can't we compare types of function arrays in C++?

Tags: c++

When I tried to compare two types of function arrays, I encountered this strange behavior.

I have test code:

```cpp
using ArrayOfFunctionsT = int (* [])(int);
ArrayOfFunctionsT functions = {};

std::cout << typeid(decltype(functions)).name() << " vs " << typeid(int (*[0])(int)).name() << "\n";
std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(functions), int (*[0])(int)>::value << "\n";
```

The result of the execution is:

```
A0_PFiiE vs A0_PFiiE
0
```

Currently I'm using gcc 10.2.1.
What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: You may not declare an array with zero elements. Either the number of elements must be explicitly specified as a positive value or the initializing list shall be non-empty.

Comment: No, it's possible. Memory just won't allocate, and sizeof will be 0

Comment: I believe zero-length arrays are a nonstandard GNU extension.  Turn on `-pedantic` and you'll get a warning.

Comment: I know that `decltype` works with expressions and `is_same` with template parameters. I think `is_same` can't work with expressions like ` int (*[0])(int)`

Comment: @Anton Umnicode  From the C++ Standard "4 An array of unknown size initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer-list containing n initializer-clauses,
where n shall be greater than zero, "

Comment: FYI, this prints `1` with clang: https://godbolt.org/z/v9Yx7aEoj

Comment: @Anton Umnicode So in fact your code is ill-formed. In such cases compilers can behave differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: zero-sized array are forbidden by C++ standard. So any result that come afterwards are compiler dependent.

---

In the comment section, people has mentioned that:

> `is_same` can't work with expressions like `int (*[0])(int)`

However, that's not the reason here, and `is_same` does work on expression similar to that. You can create a code snippet with similar result from simpler code:

```
int arr1[] = {};
int arr2[0] = {};

std::cout << typeid(decltype(arr1)).name() << " vs " << typeid(arr2).name() << "\n";
std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(arr1), decltype(arr2)>::value << "\n";
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a8M5aE5Kh)

Once again GCC prints false and Clang prints true.

---

The problem here is `functions` is a zero-sized array, which is forbidden by C++ standard. Anything that does compile relies on compiler extensions, so the results are compiler dependent. Turning on `-Wpedantic` would emit warnings or errors from the code.

More information here: [What happens if I define a 0-size array in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c)