# Cannot Write To Buffer In C

Tags: c, file

I cannot see anything wrong with this.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Reference:
    (0 offset) uint32_t size;
    (+4 offset) uint32_t elementSize;
    (+8 offset) uint32_t lastIndex;
    (+12 offset) void* data
*/

void* create_pinned_array(uint32_t elementSize, uint32_t numberOfElements, size_t sizeOfData, void* data)
{
    uint32_t size = sizeOfData + 12;
    void* memory = malloc(size);
    memset(memory, size, 4); // size
    memset(memory + 4, elementSize, 4); // elementSize
    memset(memory + 8, numberOfElements-1, 4); // lastIndex
    memcpy(memory + 12, data, sizeOfData); // actual data

    return memory;
}

int main(void)
{
    int randomList[5] = { 1, 6, 2, 9, 8 };
    void* myIntegers = create_pinned_array(sizeof(int), 5, sizeof(randomList), randomList);

    FILE* testfp = fopen("testfile.bin", "wb");
    fwrite(myIntegers, sizeof(myIntegers), 1, testfp);
    fclose(testfp);

    free(myIntegers);
    return 0;
}
```

Each time I check with xxd, instead of an ordered binary file I am getting junk data which varies every time I execute the program.

Comment: `sizeof(myIntegers)` is the size of the pointer, not the mem block.

Comment: This makes wild assumptions about the endian form of those values that I hope are justified.

Comment: `memset(memory, size, 4);`?!?!?!  Do you understand that `memset()` sets every byte of what is being set to the *same* byte value?

Comment: And please read both [**Flexible array member in C-structure**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047530/flexible-array-member-in-c-structure) and [**How to correctly use flexible array member?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769314/what-is-a-flexible-array-member-in-a-struct)

Comment: @AndrewHenle i can't believe i made that mistake. Using memcpy instead fixed it. Thx

Comment: @Hexa Simple assignment using code such as `memory->size = size;` is much preferred.  Using `memcpy()` to an offset will be wrong if the type of `memory->size` changes (for example, to `size_t` on a 64-bit system), or if the layout of the structure changes.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes but i am trying to build a data-type agnostic container kind of like a vector in c++ so using a struct api wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using memset when you mean to use memcpy.

`memset(ptr, value, N)`

Fills the bytes from ptr until ptr+n with `value`.

`memcpy(ptr, src, N)` copies N bytes from src into ptr.

Instead of this:

```
memset(memory, size, 4); // size
memset(memory + 4, elementSize, 4); // elementSize
memset(memory + 8, numberOfElements-1, 4); // lastIndex
memcpy(memory + 12, data, sizeOfData); // actual data
```

This:

```
uitn32_t lastIndex = numberOfElements-1;

memcpy(memory, &size, 4); // size
memcpy(memory + 4, &elementSize, 4); 
memcpy(memory + 8, &lastIndex, 4);   
memcpy(memory + 12, data, sizeOfData);
```

Or you could try this, which should be ok since the malloc'd memory would be aligned. (Some non-intel platforms, alignment is important if the pointer isn't on a 32-bit boundary)

```
uint32_t* header = (uint32_t*)memory;
header[0] = size;
header[1] = elementSize;
header[2] = nmberOfElements-1;
memcpy(memory + 12, data, sizeOfData);
```

This might not be your only bug.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you;'ve made a mistake with `sizeof`.

```
sizeof(myIntegers)
```

Returns the size of the void pointer, while in this case it appears `create_pinned_array` has returned a block of memory 32 bytes in size (assuming `int` is 4 bytes). Assuming a 64-bit machine, this means you're writing the first 8 bytes of your data.

Your `create_pinned_array` function should also check the return of `malloc` for success before proceeding to work with the results.