# i am looking for the right answer for this question, is this correct?

Tags: c++

> Write a function void switchEnds(int *array, int size); that is passed
> the address of the beginning of an array and the size of the array.
> The function swaps the values in the first and last entries of the
> array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void switchEnd(int *array, int size){
    int temp=array[0];
    array[0]=array[size-1];
    array[size-1]=temp;
    
}

int main()
{   const int size=5;
    int array[size]={1,2,3,4,5};
    
    switchEnd(array,size);
    
    for (int c=0;c<5;c++)
    cout<<array[c]<<" ";
}
```

Comment: What test cases have you checked? What makes you think this may not be correct (to the point that you'd ask a question here)?

Comment: Please choose a title which is useful for others with the same problem.

Comment: Would fail with a size zero array, but there isn't much you can do with a size zero array anyway, so I'm not sure it's worth testing for it. The program is probably already broken by that point.

Comment: If `size==1`, there is no need to go through with swapping -- just return `array[0]`.

Comment: @user4581301 unlike `std::vector`, an array [can not be "size zero"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c)

Comment: @Dara Moustafa Enclose the code of the function in the if statement if ( not ( size < 2 ) ) { /*...*/ }

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `if (size > 1)` would be much cleaner and more readable

Comment: @DrewDormann good point. I was thinking more `new int[0];`

Comment: Please see: [Why is "Is this correct?" an off topic question, and what should I ask instead?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359466)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. Your way is the straight forward way. But the question reminds me of some questions of c++ courses, where you should understand pointers.

If this is the case, then an answer like this might be better:

```cpp
void switchEnd(int *start, int size){
    int *end = start + size - 1;

    int temp=*start
    *start = *end
    *end = temp
}
```

Be aware that this solution is not the nice way. It is hard to understand and unhandy. So if you want to implement something like this somewhere in your code, use your solution.

Or better:

```cpp
void switchEnd(int *array, int size){
    std::swap(array[0], array[size-1]);
}
```