# Scanf char in for is weird

Tags: c, loops, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("0");
        char a[0];
        scanf("%c", a);
    }
}
```

I write this code and for every char in input, it loops an extra time without scanning again. So bash shows:

0 [i input '1', then:]
0011
000111
0000

Then loop terminates. It is like it saves the chars in scanf buffer and removes one by one each loop, rereading them extra. But why?

Comment: How much memory do you think is reserved by `char a[0];` (even if the compiler allows it)? Following from that, where do you think the input from `scanf("%c", a);` will be stored?

Comment: Do please learn to use spaces and (especially) indentation to improve your code's readability.  I've helped you out this time.

Comment: Please see [What happens if I define a 0-size array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c)

Comment: Think about it: when you "input '1'", what are your exact keypresses?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code has the following serious problem:

You are not allocating sufficient space for `scanf` to write a character. Passing an insufficiently large memory buffer to `scanf` causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should change `char a[0];` to `char a[1];`, or better: Simply write `char a;` and change `scanf("%c", a);` to `scanf("%c", &a);`.

Now, to answer your actual question:

You are not taking into account that the newline character `'\n'` is also part of the input. It is this character that you are registering as an additional character.

If you want the newline character to be discarded, then you could change

```
scanf( "%c", &a );
```

to:

```
scanf( " %c", &a );
```

This will cause `scanf` to discard all whitespace characters (i.e. spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) before attempting to match a character. That way, `scanf` will never match a newline character (or any other whitespace character).

If you only want newline characters to be discarded, but not spaces and other whitespace characters, then you can use these lines instead:

```
//discard any newline characters
scanf( "%*[\n]" );

//read the actual input
scanf( "%c", &a );
```

Note that in the code above, it is necessary to have two separate `scanf` function calls. You cannot combine them like this:

```
//read the actual input
scanf( "%*[\n]%c", &a );
```

The reason why you cannot do this is that the `%[]` conversion format specifier will only match a non-empty character sequence. Therefore, matching will fail if there are no newline characters. In the line `scanf( "%*[\n]" );`, it does not matter whether matching succeeds or fails, but in the line `scanf( "%*[\n]%c", &a );`, it does matter, because `scanf` won't attempt to match the second conversion format specifier if matching the first one fails.

See the [documentation for the function `scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for further information.