# Passing empty Python list to C

Tags: python, c, list, interop, ctypes

I am working with a C/C++ library that has a Python API and on the Python side I encountered this piece of code when passing a Python list to C

```py
from ctypes import c_int, c_size_t

def cvecint(o):
    return (c_int * len(o))(*o), c_size_t(len(o))
```

which when called with an empty list, returns what appears to be a 0-length array

```py
>>> cvecint([])
(<__main__.c_int_Array_0 object at 0x7f53470fa940>, c_ulong(0))
```

I thought 0-length arrays in C were not part of the standard, see [What happens if I define a 0-size array in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c). Same goes for C++, with both C arrays and `std::vector`s.

Am I missing something? This code is not standard compliant, does it work purely based on some compiler extension for 0-length arrays? And if so, is there a better way of passing an empty Python list to C (and possibly C++)?

Comment: The thing you can't have is an explicit `int a[0];`. Empty vectors are absolutely fine. And e.g. a pointer that points to the one-past-the-end element of an array is effectively a pointer to zero elements of that type.

Comment: I see, thanks. If we were to check the pointer in C however `if (p)...` it would be treated as `NULL` right?

Comment: Empty *vectors* are fine, but that's C++.  The OP is right that standard C does not support zero-length arrays.

Comment: But that does not prevent ctypes from providing a *Python* representation of a zero-length C array.  And there's good reason to think that such a thing could interoperate with C.

Comment: This is a *Python* wrapper. Did you actually try to pass it to *C*? I wonder what's the purpose of this?

Comment: In C, you can `char* x = malloc(0);` and get a valid non-null pointer to a 0-length buffer.  That's the C equivalent of the Python code.

Comment: Re "_I thought 0-length arrays in C were not part of the standard_". That's not completely correct. It is (obviously) possible to have a 0-length array. However, **defining** an array with a fixed size of 0 is not allowed.