# Why is std::array<T,0> sized and aligned according to T in libc++?

Tags: c++, libc++, stdarray

In libc++, the specialization of `std::array<T,0>` has a member (`const`) `char` array, which is aligned and sized according to `T` ([source](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/array#L285)). I wonder what is the reason for this implementation since this member (`__elems_`) does not seem to be used anywhere. For comparison, [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/array#L61) uses an empty member, and [Microsoft STL](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/array#L766) uses an empty member if `T` is not default-constructible (otherwise, it creates a single-element array).

Live demo of the difference: https://godbolt.org/z/1o167na6z

Comment: Why is `array<T, 0>` even a thing?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili makes generic programming eaiser

Comment: I would guess that they aren't particularly concerned with how the size zero case behaves

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am unconvinced that allowing instantiation of a generic function that effectively achieves nothing is beneficial.

Comment: @Ayxan - It saves *you* from specializing for size 0. Just loop over the array elements, and it works. Same reason for allowing `new int[0]` - it returns a pointer to no elements.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili off the top of my head one use case could be a structure with a fixed size cache, having a cache of size 0 would be perfectly valid

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Another example might be a template that is recursively instantiated with the base case that involves 0.

Comment: @DanielLangr Hmm. I feel like it might lead to more harm than good by allowing potentially unexpected cases to go unnoticed. I don't usually expect an array to be empty, but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`std::array` is allowed to have a zero size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) but the [underlying c arrays can't be zero-sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c). Therefore the implementations will need some special case to handle this.

The standard doesn't specify what this implementation must be or really place many constraints on the behaviour, calling `front()` or `back()` is undefined behaviour. There is one constraint that `array.begin() == array.end()`. As there are not many constraints you'd expect different implementations to use different workarounds for it.

Libc++ originally used a single element array but this doesn't work with non-default constructible types. In order to maintain ABI compatibility this [was replaced](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/59cdf90ac8bea16abbb9d637c5124e69d2c75c09) with a `char` array of the same size.

Comment: I agree, but implementations typically try to be as efficient as possible if there is no reason to do otherwise.

Comment: @DanielLangr What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: @PasserBy A single allocated byte is more (memory-)efficient than `sizeof(T)` bytes (with additional possible padding).

Comment: Thanks, the update seems to include the answer, i.e., the ABI compatibility.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Yes, with MSVC, this code really prints `X` on the console: `struct X{ X() { std::cout << "X"; } }; int main() { std::array<X, 0> a; }`.