What is the rationale for 0-size arrays?
Both GCC and Clang support (as an extension) 0-size (also called "0-length") arrays.
What is the rationale for 0-size arrays (example int x[0])?

See some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c.

I assume you have read each compilers documentation for this, doesn't that say anything?

It's an old pre-C99 way to have what C99 calls flexible array members of structs.

And can you please [edit] your question to be more explicit about what you mean... Do you mean something like int a1[0]; or something like int a2[];?

@Someprogrammerdude I mean int a1[0]; because in int a2[]; a2 is an array of unknown size.

Most gcc extensions have no rationale. Their rationale tends to be "it doesn't exist so we must have it". Kind of like weeds in your garden are appearing there without much of an explanation where they came from or what they are good for. They are just popping up by themselves randomly over time, making everything ugly and attracting bugs. "If it ain't broken, it ain't got enough features yet."


What is the rationale for 0-size arrays?

Taking you to mean an explicit zero length:
int array[0];

The GCC manual describes it as

useful as the last element of a structure that is really a header for a variable-length object

. That's the same purpose served by C99+ flexible array members, as the manual goes on to observe, and it recommends FAMs over zero-length arrays for this purpose.  The manual also contrasts with pre-C99 conventional practice of using a length-1 array for the same purpose, observing that the two have different effects on the size of the host structure.  I take that to be the original inspiration for the extension, and I take continued support to be for backwards compatibility.
The manual does not discuss using zero-length arrays in other contexts, but GCC does accept that.  No rationale is given, but I take it to be for consistency with allowing it for structure members.  C semantics can largely be squared with such arrays, though they are not very useful.
As for Clang, I don't find this extension documented among Clang / LLVM language extensions.  If it is supported by that system then my best guess would be that that is for compatibility with GCC, though it could also be a case of parallel evolution.

Two things to consider:
In the physical world, an empty box is different than not having a box.
It may also help when moving code from one language to another, if the source language allowed empty arrays.

NMDV, but a zero-length array is more like a box with zero volume than like one that is merely empty.  Having a zero-volume box might be different from not having a box at all, but that's not entirely clear-cut.
