# Compilation error while accessing address of zero length array in C

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [zero length arrays vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627364/zero-length-arrays-vs-pointers)

Some new compilers throw up compilation error for below case

```
struct test {
int length;
char data[0];
};

int main(void)
{
char string[20] = {0};
struct test *t;

//Some code

memcpy(string, t->data, 19); //Compilation error 
}
```

However this gets resolved if I do like this.

```
memcpy(string, &(t->data[0]), 19);
```

Any reason why some new compilers are enforcing this restriction?

Edited to correct mistakes

Comment: Please consider if you think it would be helpful to include the actual error you're getting, verbatim from the compiler.

Comment: This happens in icc (intel c compiler)

Comment: This is error: error #170: pointer points outside of underlying object

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with this:

```
struct test t;

memcpy(string, test->data, 19);
```

? Hint, `test` is a *type*.

EDIT: as to the real answer, see this question: [zero length arrays vs. pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627364/zero-length-arrays-vs-pointers) (or similar questions on SO)

Comment: Sorry it should have been memcpy(string, t->data, 19);

Answer (score 0):

Array can't have `0` size .

Here is the Standard:

ISO 9899:2011 6.7.6.2:

```
   If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value
   greater than zero
```

And second

use this:

```
memcpy(string,t->data,19); instead of what you have used.
```

Comment: Yeah but this is in ISO c, the concept of zero lengh arrays to indicate a member which can latter be malloced is common. ISO C allows using array[]; for that (note no size given) where as gcc allows array[0];